# Does the language matter for programs that tie into linux

Tags: linux, web-hosting

I'm wondering about control panels program like cPanel, Plesk, etc. These programs help the linux user control linux in a more visual way. Does the language in which they were written matter. cPanel is written in Perl, but I've seen others written in PHP and even in C++. Are there advantages or disadvantages to using each language for a control panel type program or basically a program like this that ties into linux at this level?

Comment: There are subtleties to each language that make it better than another language for certain problems, but that is way out of scope for this site.

Comment: Redirect question to [StackOverflow](http://www.stackoverflow.com)?

Answer (score 2):

Strictly speaking, if it does the job it doesn't 'matter' what it is written in.

PHP, perl or any interpreted 'scripting' language probably make more sense for control panels like these, since there isn't [as far as I can tell] much need to directly address memory.

CPanel is a beastly hog but useful for people too ignorant or lazy to manage their own services.

edit: I should say it **matters** in that whatever language it is written on will need to be present on your server. So if it's PHP, you'll need the appropriate version of PHP, same for perl.

Answer (score 1):

Tell ya what: I'll give you a nickel if you write one in assembler.

If that doesn't answer your question, you're either not paying attention or not asking the right question.

Comment: I'm probably both. Can you explain your point?

Answer (score 1):

If they run and do the job, they're fine. No real advantage based on language of implementation.

Answer (score 1):

Mono still has a stigma and will inhibit adoption of your software somewhat, but other than that it doesn't matter greatly.